# What is the coefficient of the $x^{302}$

Tags: combinations

What's the coefficient of the $x^{302}$ in the following expression:

$$\dfrac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^6)}$$

I don't know where to start. Also x are in the denominator how this expression can have x to power of a positive term?

Comment: Recall $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots$ so there are usually positive powers of $x$ in Taylor series of such,

Comment: @coffeemath is it related to generating functions too?

Comment: Yes. these are generating functions, which when Taylor series are found, the coefficient of $x^n$ is the term $a_n$ of some sequence of interest. They are "formal" series i.e. convergence is not considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $[x^a](...)$ be the coefficient of $x^a$ in $(...)$.

Notice in the expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^6)}$, the monomials from $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ factors in denominator have exponents divisible by $3$ and $302 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. One must take a $x^2$ from $1^{st}$ factor to get $302$. As a result,

$$
K \stackrel{def}{=} [x^{302}]\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^6)}
= [x^{300}]\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^6)}
$$
We can rewrite RHS as $$[x^{300}]\frac{1 + x^2 + x^4}{(1-x^3)(1-x^6)^2}$$
Notice the $x^2$ and $x^4$ in numerator cannot contribute to $x^{300}$ because the exponent in denominator are all divisible by $3$ and $3$ dividies $300$. We have

$$K = [x^{300}]\frac{1}{(1-x^3)(1-x^6)^2} = [y^{100}]\frac{1}{(1-y)(1-y^2)^2}
= [y^{100}]\frac{1+y}{(1-y^2)^3}
$$
Once again, the $y$ in numerator cannot contribute to $y^{100}$ because the exponents in denominator are all divisible by $2$ and $2$ divides $100$. This implies

$$K = [y^{100}]\frac1{(1-y^2)^3} = [z^{50}]\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}$$

Recall the power series expansion for $|z| < 1$.
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^m} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m-1+k}{k} z^k$$

This means the coefficient $K$ we seek equals to $\binom{50+2}{2} = 1326$.

Comment: No, it's good now.

Answer (score 2):

If $|x|<1$, then the sum of a geometric series tells us that $$\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$$

As $|x|<1$, $|x^2|,|x^3|, |x^6|<1$ and so we may substitute $x$ for $x^2, x^3$ or $x^6$ in the previous expression, obtaining $$\dfrac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^6)}=\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x^3}\dfrac{1}{1-x^6}=(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k})\cdot(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{3k})\cdot(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{6k})$$

The coefficient of $x^{302}$ can be found then either multiplying those series or as the number of non-negative integer solutions $x_1,x_2,x_3$ of $$2x_1+3x_2+6x_3=302$$

Comment: Can you explain how to solve the equation? I know how to solve them if the coefficient's are 1.

Comment: With a computer ;) Normally you go the other way around, that is, you use generating functions and their coefficients to find the number of solutions

Comment: but I don't have access to computer in exam :( There must be a way to solve it